# Check(validate) send form data with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I,m try check(validate) form data by using AJAX.
First i create callback function with AJAX request(in my example it's field time)
When i found same record in database, my NodeJS server response with value false, it's means we have record and we don't need add second record with that time).

My problem is that the form is still sent, regardless of the server response.

here my code(front end)

```
function funABC(mdata,callback){
    console.log(mdata);
    $.ajax({
      url:'/dashboard/materials/checkshowrange',
      method: 'GET',      
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data:mdata,
      success: callback ,
     // error:callback,

    });
  }  


 $('.addForm').on('submit', function (event) {
    let form = $('.addForm');
    if (form[0].checkValidity() === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
     // return false;
    }

event.preventDefault();
checkdata = {
        time_show : document.querySelector('.addForm').elements.time_show.value
      }
    functABC(checkdata,function(result) {     
      console.log(result); 
      if (result == 'true') {
        alert(`For time: ${checkdata. time_show} there is already an event, choose a different time`);        
        return false;
      } 
    })


form.addClass('was-validated');


some operations with form data, then send with ajax

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/dashboard/materials/add",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
          setTimeout(location.href = '/dashboard/materials', 10000);
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(formdata)
      });


});
```

Comment: regardless of forms validity, you need to prevent default behavior of form submit event. I see you do that under a if condition. You need to do it outside of your funABC()

Comment: Remember the line starting with " $('.addForm').on...". Actually, you need to put that outside of the ABC function. You need to stop default behavior of form submit.

Comment: @adp7 I moved all  code inside the function with a callback, now everything seems to work fine

Answer (score 1):

How and where did you call that post request ?
May be you would need to move post request into the callback

```js
function funABC(mdata, callback) {
    console.log(mdata);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/dashboard/materials/checkshowrange',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: mdata,
        success: callback,
        // error:callback,

    });
}

$('.addForm').on('submit', function(event) {
    let form = $('.addForm');
    if (form[0].checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        // return false;
    }

    event.preventDefault();
    checkdata = {
        time_show: document.querySelector('.addForm').elements.time_show.value
    }
    functABC(checkdata, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        if (result == 'true') {
            alert(`For time: ${checkdata. time_show} there is already an event, choose a different time`);
            return false;
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/dashboard/materials/add",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function(data) {
                    setTimeout(location.href = '/dashboard/materials', 10000);
                },
                data: JSON.stringify(formdata)
            });
        }
    })


    form.addClass('was-validated');

});
```

Or you could async false for validation request

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/dashboard/materials/checkshowrange',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: mdata,
    success: callback,
    async: false,
    // error:callback,

});
```

Comment: Thx man, i moved all insert code into callback function almost like your example. now everything seems to work fine. What if I need validate not one value, may i use promise?

Comment: didnt get it, could you send me example ?